# Tray Icon Missing Rssowl Fedora 18

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I have been an avid user of RSSOwl & now have ported mine OS to Fedora 18. Everything works fine including the transfer of .rssowl2 (backup folder) to new Fedora. However when minimised or exited to tray tray icon is missing...
[image]

notifications are OK I  too can right-click tray icon...

/* Details Added */

RssOwl can be downloaded as a zip file. it has a got a binary & an xpm file...You just execute binary (I symlinked it to /bin) & app starts so I manually created .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Network;
Exec=rssowl
Icon=/home/usama/Programs/rssowl/RSSOwl.png
Name=RSSOwl
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

I converted that .xpm file to .png to be used as desktop icon. Now I copied RSSOwl.png to /usr/share/pixmaps with **no success** & when copied RSSOwl.png to /usr/share/icons/gnome/24x24/apps well **success** happened but very tiny icon :(

Comment: You have `Icon=/home/usama/Programs/rssowl/RSSOwl.png`. Have you tried to put the icon in the `/usr/share/pixmaps/RSSOwl.png` and set `Icon=RSSOwl.png` in your .desktop file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that app, but I know that means your icon theme doesn't have the required icon, i.e `apps/24/XX.png`,

A stupid solution is copy it from somewhere, i.e check the Icon= line in /usr/share/applications/XX.desktop, and copy it to your theme dir.

P.S does the app icon show correctly when you search for the app?

Comment: Nay, that didn't work. Details added

Comment: the proper localtion is /usr/share/pixmap